# How to prevent Liquibase from executing a modified version of the changelog?

Tags: liquibase

I'm running Liquibase 3.6.2 and am looking for a way to prevent developers from modifying an existing changelog by adding/removing changesets.  Liquibase defines a changeset as non-mutable; changing any parameter or dependency in a changeset will throw a violation error, but unfortunately, I do not see any way to prevent this from a changelog perspective.

Essentially, I'm trying to implement a convention that once a changelog is run, it can no longer be modified.  New changesets must be added to a newer changelog instead.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this?  How does everyone else manage non-mutability of changelogs?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "once a changelog is run"? There are multiple environments where changelog/changesets will be executed. Some of them do not exist yet - think about a new colleague joining your team in one month and setting up his local environment. Should changelog be open for modifications until then?

Comment: @IllyaKysil Your comment made me think a bit, and I've come to realize that you're right.  In my mind, the definition is once a changelog is executed on a particular system, that it cannot be re-executed a second time.  But then what prevents someone from having modified it and running the modified version on a clean DB?  Nothing.  So with a  little more thought, it makes sense that it is based on the changesets and not the changelog.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

once a changelog is run, it can no longer be modified and of you do, you will get checksum error. The best practice is to always add new changesets that needs to be added in relate to the existing changeset.